# JHipster 3 error during CORS request

Tags: angularjs, rest, cors, jhipster

Currently I'm working on JHipster 3(migrating from JHipster 2). Some of my module is requested from RESFTful to get JSON data.

Here the sample code in JHipster 2: --> (working)

```
'use strict';

angular.module('newsletterApp')
    .factory('UserBirthday', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://localhost:8081/BirthDay/Rest/WebService/GetFeeds', {}, {
                'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
                'get': {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: true,
                    transformResponse: function (data) {
                        data = angular.fromJson(data);
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

And for Jhipster 3:

```
    (function(){
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('newsletterApp')
            .factory('EmployeeBirthday', EmployeeBirthday);

        EmployeeBirthday.$inject = ['$resource'];

        function EmployeeBirthday($resource){
            return $resource('http://localhost:8081/BirthDay/Rest/WebService/GetFeeds', {}, {
                'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
                'get': {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: true,
                    transformResponse: function (data) {
                        data = angular.fromJson(data);
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            });
        } })();
```

And I got Error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8081/BirthDay/Rest/WebService/GetFeeds. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

In application.yml also already enabled for CORS

```
cors: #By default CORS are not enabled. Uncomment to enable.
        allowed-origins: "*"
        allowed-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
        allowed-headers: "*"
        exposed-headers:
        allow-credentials: true
        max-age: 1800
```

Any advice to solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

allowed-origin must be specified (e.g. http://localhost:9000) and cannot be Wildcard * in combination with allow-credentials: true.